# Calling upstart job from inside python code causes process freeze

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, upstart

I have a situation where I want to start an upstart job from inside my python code. The job  to be started is itself written in python(that should not matter here)

Here is what my upstart job config(`/etc/init/test.conf`) looks like

```
normal exit 0
respawn
respawn limit 5 300
instance $db

chdir /home/talha/conn/test/
script
   exec /usr/bin/python test.py $db
end script
```

My calling python code to start this job sits inside a Django project which is hooked to run via wsgi_mod in Apache. Since apache runs under `www-data`  I need to use `sudo` to launch upstart.(I have given apache the permissions to run `start`/`stop`.)

My calling python code looks like this

```
cmd = "sudo start test db="+ db_name
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Now the service is started. Here is the output from `ps aux`

```
S root      9063  8929  0  80   0 -  4751 poll_s 23:09 ?00:00:00 sudo start    
test db=testdb
4 Z root      9064  9063  0  80   0 -     0 exit   00:00:00 [start]<defunct>
0 S root      9066  1  0  80   0 -  9351 poll_s 23:09 ?00:00:00 python 
test.py testdb
```

Note here the process `sudo start test db=testdb` with pid `9063` running. This is the problem. It never exits. Running `strace` on this process shows that it is stuck somewhere in `SELECT`... There is also a zombie process.The actual service `python test.py` runs fine however..

Similarly when I try to stop the service through the code

```
cmd = "sudo stop test db="+ db_name
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The actual service is killed, but the starting/stopping process are stuck

```
4 S root      9063  1  0  80   0 -  4751 poll_s 23:09 ?00:00:00 sudo start 
test db=testdb
4 S root      9267  1  0  80   0 -  4751 poll_s 23:11 ?00:00:00 sudo stop   
test db=testdb
```

Any idea/help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `close_fds=True, stdin=DEVNULL,stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT, preexec_fn=os.setsid` and use `rc = call(..)` instead of Popen?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I have updated the description. I was missing out on a zombie process that is also created. Could this be the reason

Comment: `start` is dead but its parent `sudo` is alive so if `sudo` haven't called `waitpid` for the `start` process or reaped it other way; it stays zombie. It seems unrelated to the freeze. Have you tried to call with the parameters I've provided? Also try to call outside `apache` and/or using different user. Use `subprocess.check_call` to get a traceback.